# The local variable noun may not have been initialized

Tags: java

I get this "The local variable noun may not have been initialized" error and I don't know why? if I initialize the variable to null which is `noun = null`, the program crashes as soon as it executes `System.out.println("Enter noun: ");`

```
    int age;
    System.out.println("Enter your age: ");
    age = input.nextInt();
    String name, adjective, adverb, verb, noun;

    if(age > 13) {

        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        name = input.nextLine();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter adjective: ");
        adjective = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter noun: ");
        if(noun.equals("dork")){
            System.out.println("That language is not allowed. Exiting");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
        noun = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter adverb: ");
        adverb = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter verb: ");
        verb = input.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("%s is a %s %s. They are always %s %s", name, adjective, noun, adverb, verb);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Your age is %s and You're still young to access this information", age);


    }
```

Comment: if noun is `null` `noun.equals("dork")` crashes .

Comment: You're missing `noun = input.nextLine();`

Answer (score 3):

The error message you are getting is being caused by using the variable `noun` at a point where it might not have been initialized already in the code.  You can try setting `noun` to user input *before* you check its value.  This should get rid of the error while also leaving your code in a more sensible and readable position:

```
System.out.println("Enter noun: ");
noun = input.nextLine();
if (noun.equals("dork")) {
    System.out.println("That language is not allowed. Exiting");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

```
if(noun.equals("dork")){
```

Put this line before the if

```
noun = input.nextLine();
```